# ¿Por qué este tipo de ciclo `for` funciona de una manera distinta a la de un ciclo `for` normal?

Tags: java, lista, loops, ciclos, iteradores

Tengo el siguiente código y resulta que cuando lo corro, ejecuta primero `for (ListIterator it = pila1.listIterator(pila1.size()); it.hasPrevious();)`, luego `for (ListIterator itt = pila2.listIterator(pila2.size()); itt.hasPrevious();)` y luego lo que resta del codigo, y luego vuelve a `for (ListIterator it = pila1.listIterator(pila1.size()); it.hasPrevious();)`, es decir, no termina de recorrer todos los elementos del segundo ciclo `for`,¿Por qué?.

**Notas:** La estructura es `for(alguna_declaracion; cuantas_veces_se_ejecutara;)`. El programa funciona bien:)

```
public class ClaseEjercicio31ago {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);

    List<Integer> pila1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> pila2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> cola = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    System.out.println("Introduzca los digitos (5) para la pila1");
    for (char digito : leer.nextLine().toCharArray()) {
        pila1.add(digito - '0');
    }

    System.out.println("Introduzca los digitos (5) para la pila2");
    for (char digito : leer.nextLine().toCharArray()) {
        pila2.add(digito - '0');
    }

    int uno = 0;

    for (ListIterator it = pila1.listIterator(pila1.size()); it.hasPrevious();) {
        for (ListIterator itt = pila2.listIterator(pila2.size()); itt.hasPrevious();) {

            int n1 = (Integer) it.previous();
            int n2 = (Integer) itt.previous();

            int n3 = (n1 + n2 + uno);

            if (n3 >= 10) {
                cola.add(n3 - 10);
                uno = 1;

            } else {
                cola.add(n3 + uno);
            }
            it.remove();
            itt.remove();
        }

    }
    if (uno == 1) {
        cola.add(1);
    }

    System.out.println("La suma de las pilas es:");

    for (Iterator it = cola.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        int t = (Integer) it.next();
        System.out.print("\n " + t + "\n");
        it.remove();
    }
```

Comment: NOta: También, cualquier sugerencia para mejorar la implementación del codigo es bienvenida:)

Comment: ¿Qué se supone que hace el código que mencionas?

Comment: Devuelve el resultado de la suma entre 2 números @SJuan76

Comment: por ejemplo, supongamos que pila1=11111 y pila2=99999, entonces cola=111110. @SJuan76

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Deberías explicar qué es lo que debería hacer tu código

De todas maneras, me parece entender que tu código recibe dos números, los almacena en sendas listas y luego los suma cifra por cifra.

### Comportamiento de los bucles

El problema que tienes es que **No necesitas dos bucles**.

Si lo que quieres es sumar dos listas elemento a elemento, tienes que hacer un número de ciclos **exactamente igual al tamaño de la lista más grande**, lo cual se resuelve iterando a través de esa lista. Lo que tú pretendes hacer es iterar a través de ambas listas, pero hacerlo un número de veces igual al tamaño de la otra lista. Es decir, **Te sobran muchos ciclos**.

En términos matemáticos, podemos decir que si `n = m = lista2.size();`, tú quieres hacer `n * m` ciclos cuando en realidad necesitas solo `n` ciclos.

Me he tomado la libertad de modificar tu código. El código dentro de los bucles me ha quedado así:

```
public static void sumarListas(List<Integer> pila1, List<Integer> pila2, List<Integer> cola) {        
    int uno = 0;
    int n1;
    int n2;
    int n3;
    
    //Dos Iterators, pero solo un bucle
    ListIterator<Integer> it = pila1.listIterator(pila1.size());
    for (ListIterator<Integer> itt = pila2.listIterator(pila2.size()); itt.hasPrevious();) {

        n1 = it.previous();
        n2 = itt.previous();
        n3 = (n1 + n2 + uno);

        if (n3 >= 10) {
            cola.add(n3 - 10);
            uno = 1;

        } else {  //Si no es mayor que diez, uno tiene que ser 0
            cola.add(n3);  //No tenía sentido sumarle uno más solo por ser mayor de diez
            uno = 0;
        }
    }

    if (uno == 1) {
        cola.add(1);
    }

}
```

Notarás que he modificado tu `else`, creo que este es el comportamiento que debería tener.

### Mejora de código

En cuanto a la mejora de código, te puedo dar un par de reglas generales que mejorarán lo bien que se pueda leer, testear y modificar tu código.

- **Ponles nombres significativos a tus variables**. Es mucho más fácil entender un código cuyas variables te explican qué son con solo leer su nombre.
- **Separa todo lo posible la lógica en métodos** Si tienes toda tu lógica en el método `main`, es difícil de leer y testear. Si lo separas en métodos pequeños que se ocupen de una única cosa y, además, nombras esos métodos de manera adecuada (Explicando lo que hacen) podrás entender mejor qué ocurre en tu código.
- **Generalmente, utiliza la solución más simple** Una solución simple permite leer el código más fácilmente que una solución compleja.

Refiriéndome a tu código en concreto, puedo decirte:

- El método estático `Character.getNumericValue()` es más fácil de leer que `digito - '0'`. Además te protege contra número no Unicode.
- A partir de Java 7, No tienes por qué especificar el tipo genérico en la instanciación. Es decir: `List<Integer> pila1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();` es lo mismo que `List<Integer> pila1 = new ArrayList<>();`
- Crear dos `Iterator` me parece demasiado para iterar una lista y operar dos. Creo que un bucle `for` normal te hubiera servido mejor.
- El eliminar los elementos ya iterados de la lista no te sirve de nada, más que para consumir más tiempo de procesador. Si no necesitas quitarlos, no lo hagas.
- A partir de Java 8, las operaciones con listas se han simplificado bastante. Consulta [`Streams`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html), [Expresiones lambda](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html), la interfaz [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) y [Referencias de métodos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

He reescrito tu código siguiendo los criterios que te he listado:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);

    List<Integer> numeroASumar1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> numeroASumar2 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> resultado = new ArrayList<>();

    recogerListas(leer, numeroASumar1, numeroASumar2);

    sumarListas(numeroASumar1, numeroASumar2, resultado);

    System.out.println("La suma de las pilas es:");        
    escribirLista(resultado);
}

public static void recogerListas(Scanner leer, List<Integer> listaALlenar1, List<Integer> listaALlenar2)
{
    //A mi me gusta separar los métodos lo mas posible y hubiera separado
    //la lectura de la línea y la asignacion a las listas, pero me parecia
    //demasiado para este ejemplo
    System.out.println("Introduzca los digitos (5) para la pila1");        
    for (char digito : leer.nextLine().toCharArray()) {
        listaALlenar1.add(digito - '0');
    }

    System.out.println("Introduzca los digitos (5) para la pila2");
    for (char digito : leer.nextLine().toCharArray()) {
        listaALlenar2.add(digito - '0');
    }
}

public static void escribirLista(List<Integer> lista)
{
    //Utiliza java 8 
    lista.forEach(System.out::println);
}

public static void sumarListas(List<Integer> numeroASumar1, List<Integer> numeroASumar2, List<Integer> resultado) {
    int acarreo = 0;
    int suma;
    
    //bucle for invertido
    for (int i = numeroASumar1.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        suma = numeroASumar1.get(i) + numeroASumar2.get(i) + acarreo;
        if (suma >= 10) {
            suma -= 10;
            acarreo = 1;
        } else {
            acarreo = 0;
        }
        resultado.add(suma);            
    }
    if (acarreo == 1) resultado.add(acarreo);
}
```

Incidentalmente, la suma de las listas *probablemente* se podría haber solucionado en una o dos líneas de código con Streams y sus métodos `map()` y `filter()`. Intentaré hacerlo más tarde si se requiere.

Comment: A lo mejor y si, el ejercicio se podría resolverse en 2 patadas usando maps u otras cosas, pero aun no he visto maps ni Streams, entonces no los podre ocupar para la solución de ejercicios.

Comment: Mi codigo iba a tronar aquí: `cola.add(n3+uno);` :D..gracias por tu ayuda!

Answer (score 2):

El tipo de for que utilizas es (si mas no recuerdo) el mas básico que hay y el primero, el cual se lee de la siguiente forma:

```
//  i = 0  -> Indicas el valor inicial de la variable que iterará el array
//  i < listaObjeto.size() -> Indicas la condición con la cual dejará de iterar el array cuando se cumpla, en este caso cuando "i" sea menor que el tamaño de tu array.
//  i ++   -> El crecimiento del valor de la variable, en este caso se le suma +1 con cada iteración.
for (i = 0 ; i < listaObjeto.size() ; i++){
    //  Tu código.
    Objeto o = listaObjetos.get(i);
}
```

Un inconveniente que se tiene con este for es que, si no defines bien la condición con la cual iterar, puede que no recorras totalmente el array o te salte una Excepción por un índice fuera del array.

En vez de ella, para recorrer objetos te recomiendo utilizar esta forma de for:

```
//  Objeto o    -> Variable instanciada del tipo de tu objeto, y que tomará el valor de cada uno dentro del array.
//  objetoLista -> Array de Objeto a iterar.
for(Objeto o : obejtoLista){
    //  Tu código
}
```

Al tener la variable **o** del tipo **Objeto** esta iterará todos los objetos dentro del array. Espero mi respuesta te haya ayudado y servido. Saludos.

Comment: pero si te das cuenta, esos `for`s que tengo en mi codigo, trabajan de una manera rara, es decir, supongamos que pila1=1234 y pila2=5678, entonces el codigo lo que hace es: toma el 4 y lo suma con el 8.Luego toma el 3 y lo suma con el 7, y asi sucesivamente. Ahora, un `for` "normal", hubiese hecho lo siguiente: toma el 4 y lo suma con el 8, luego con el mismo 4, lo sumaria con el 7, y luego con el 6 y asi...

Comment: Te recomiendo que cambies el for que estas usando, ya que las variables it e itt me da la sensacion que la estas cargando de una forma incorrecta ya que no se xq le pasas el size de pila1 al metodo listIterator.

Comment: si la estoy cargando de una manera incorrecta, porque no marca error? :D

Answer (score 2):

```
for (ListIterator it = pila1.listIterator(pila1.size()); it.hasPrevious();) {
    for (ListIterator itt = pila2.listIterator(pila2.size()); itt.hasPrevious();) {

        int n1 = (Integer) it.previous();
        int n2 = (Integer) itt.previous();

        int n3 = (n1 + n2 + uno);

        if (n3 >= 10) {
            cola.add(n3 - 10);
            uno = 1;

        } else {
            cola.add(n3 + uno);
        }
        it.remove();  <--
        itt.remove();  <--
    }
```

- En la primera iteración, empiezas con dos listas de 5 elementos.
- Entras en el `for` externo, obtienes un iterador al final<sup>1</sup> de la primera lista, como `hasPrevious` es `true` entras en el bucle.
- Entras en el `for` internet, obtienes un iterador al final<sup>1</sup> de la segunda lista, como `hasPrevious` es `true` entras en el bucle.
- En cada iteración del bucle interno, obtienes el elmento anterior de ambas lista, y *eliminas dicho elemento de cada lista*. Es decir, **en la primera iteración del bucle exterior vas a hacer 5 iteraciones de la ambas listas y eliminar 5 elementos de ambas listas**, dejando las dos listas vacías y los dos iteradores al principio de sus respectivas listas.

  A partir de ese punto, tanto `it.hasPrevious()` como `itt.hasPrevious()` devuelven false así que se sale de ambos `for`.

En cuando a la solución, no está claro qué es lo que tiene que hacer el código así que no puede haber respuesta, pero lo que sí está claro es que en el código actual uno de los `for` sobra.

---

<sup>1</sup>"Al final" significa "después del último elemento", de forma que el primer `previous` te devuelve el último elemento.